# Is it possible to turn off a branch forwarding in STM32F1xx?

Tags: stm32, assembler

[This article](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/e/Introduction/Branch-target-forwarding) tells about the branch forwarding mechanism. Because of this mechanism the time of a loop is not the same from iteration to iteration. Is it possible to turn off this mechanism or give some tips to it to make iteration isochronus on STM32F103RB?

In common case there are more source of jitter in code execution. But my code is very small. Excluding initialization and constants definition it consists of this:

```
.macro WAIT_MYCLK_RISE
  rise_loop_\@:
  LDR  R0, [R4]
  ANDS R0, R0, MYCLK_PIN
  BEQ  rise_loop_\@
.endm

.macro WAIT_MYCLK_FALL
  fall_loop_\@:
  LDR  R0, [R4]
  ORRS R0, R0, MYCLK_PIN
  EORS R0, R0, FFFF_FFFF
  BEQ  fall_loop_\@
.endm

asm_func:
  LDR R1, =GPIO_PIN_5
  LDR R2, =0x00000000
  LDR R3, =GPIOA_ODR
  LDR R4, =GPIOB_IDR
  loop:
    WAIT_MYCLK_RISE
    STR R1, [R3]//blink
    STR R2, [R3]
    WAIT_MYCLK_FALL
    STR R1, [R3]//blink
    STR R2, [R3]
  B loop
```

There is no interrupts or something else that can gives jitter except the instruction prefetcher.

Comment: The features in F1 parts vary, which F1 part?

Comment: Just poll a timer flag? What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Jeroen3 I fix the question: STM32F103RB

Comment: _Why_ would you want to turn it off and thereby make your code slower - that is the actual problem you are trying to solve. Because making code run slower for the heck of it is usually not anyone's goal. As in, are you using busy-wait loops for timing where you should be using hardware timers.

Comment: This is a very simple form of branch prediction more similar to pipelining than anything else. Pipelining being a mechanism available in the core on much simpler ISA than Cortex M as well. None of it is "branch prediction" in the normal sense, this is only a simple mechanism to ease issues with flash wait states. And the obvious solution to disable/invalidate the feature is therefore to clock the core slow enough that wait states aren't necessary.

Comment: I have deleted two comments and edited another (two different people involved). MOST users here are trying to help and it is usually a good idea to assume that intentions are good until experience shows that may not be the case. Comments on people's competence are usually not a good idea.

Comment: Arseniy, these types of processors aren't *meant* to give you constant execution speed. Instead, they give you things that are *better*, namely tight integration with timers, well-layerable interrupts, and the opportunity to offload the most common source of timing uncertainty – memory and peripheral bus access – to a DMA controller. So, you're basically asking "I bought a 2018 VW Golf, and I can't find the crank handle; how can I emulate the crank start on a 1950 Citroën 2CV". And the answer is: you don't. Your approach isn't the right one for the car (microcontroller) you have.

Comment: if you are looking for a consistent and repeatable loop time then I think for these parts you have to run it in ram. you likely want to disable any branch prediction if it is enabled. the m3 I do not think has a fetch line or fetch line issue so from one compile to the next it should be consistent.

Comment: you should be using a timer for this or even the spi controller or something to get good timing, this is not a pic.

Comment: the raspberry pi pico has a very nice gpio engine that makes any waveform somewhat easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the flash prefetcher `FLASH_ACR->PRFTBE`, but to get consistent results you also have to slow down the flash memory into 0 wait state speeds*.

*0 wait states, if 0 < SYSCLK <= 24 MHz

Maybe if you explain the [original problem](https://xyproblem.info/) you want to solve we can provide a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Alas, but the clearing FLASH_ACR->PRFTBE does't lead to isochronous execution of instructions. I add nessesarry correction in my code and I see In the debugger that the PRFTBE bit is clearing. But on the oscilloscope I see that my code still runs from time to time for 8...24 clocks of SYSCLK.

Comment: @Arseniy There are more source of jitter in code execution than only the prefetcher. Interrupts, bus contention, data synchronization. Maybe if you can tell us what you want to achieve we can direct our answers better.

Comment: I have update my question with my code. I do not use any interrupts.

Comment: the prefetch in the flash acr has to do with ST not arm.

Comment: bp is bit 18 of the ccr